# Android JSON Not working

Tags: php, android, json, web-services

I have following code and i want to pass additional parameter in JSON.getJSONfromURL() method but when i check on android it throws this exception

> 04-11 11:58:18.929: E/AndroidRuntime(566): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 04-11
>   11:58:18.929: E/AndroidRuntime(566): java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{cyclist.project/cyclist.project.user_discussion}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 04-11 11:58:18.929:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(566):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
>   04-11 11:58:18.929: E/AndroidRuntime(566):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>   04-11 11:58:18.929: E/AndroidRuntime(566):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125) 04-11
>   11:58:18.929: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>   04-11 11:58:18.929: E/AndroidRuntime(566):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 04-11
>   11:58:18.929: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 04-11 11:58:18.929:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(566):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 04-11
>   11:58:18.929: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 04-11
>   11:58:18.929: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 04-11 11:58:18.929:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(566):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   04-11 11:58:18.929: E/AndroidRuntime(566):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 04-11
>   11:58:18.929: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 04-11 11:58:18.929:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(566): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 04-11
>   11:58:18.929: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at
>   cyclist.project.JSON.getJSONfromURL(JSON.java:60) 04-11 11:58:18.929:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(566):    at
>   cyclist.project.user_discussion.setList(user_discussion.java:250)
>   04-11 11:58:18.929: E/AndroidRuntime(566):    at
>   cyclist.project.user_discussion.onCreate(user_discussion.java:154)
>   04-11 11:58:18.929: E/AndroidRuntime(566):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   04-11 11:58:18.929: E/AndroidRuntime(566):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
>   04-11 11:58:18.929: E/AndroidRuntime(566):    ... 11 more

Code:

```
    JSONObject json;

    try {
        json = new JSONObject(
        JSON.getJSONfromURL("http://myweb.com/ws_cyc/events_service.php?action=get_chats&title=fsfbnn" ));
    JSONArray miles = json.getJSONArray("cyc");
    JSONObject rec;
    JSONObject rec2 = null; 

    for (int i=0; i<miles.length(); i++){
                rec = miles.getJSONObject(i);
                rec2 = rec.getJSONObject("cycObject");
                new discussion_item(rec2.getString("Chats").toString());
                ImgList.add( rec2.getString("image_path").toString() );
                list.add( rec2.getString("email").toString() + ": " + rec2.getString("Chats").toString() );
            }                                   
    } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Please guide me how to pass additional parameters in JSON.getJSONfromURL() and how php will get it , my php code to catch jason is

```
$titlez = json_decode($_GET['title']);
```

Comment: its better if you check if the element exist before saying **get()**

Comment: As the error log says, it is caused by null Value being passed and attempted to be processed at *line 154* of the file `user_discussion.java`

Comment: @ SamSPICA your right, after your indication I checked the code in debug mode, turns out null was being passed. Thnx for pointint out.

Comment: @malikzeeshan it would be great if you can accept it as an answer below, so as to close the question (and in turn offer me reputation[;)]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error log says, it is caused by null Value being passed and attempted to be processed at *line 154* of the file `user_discussion.java`

Answer (score 1):

It's better used Gson to fetch JSON data, it's fast and efficient.